# How do I fix this internet connection error?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection, broadband

I am getting errors like:

```
ERR Name Resolution Failed  
ERR tunnel connection failed  
DNS probe finished nxdomain
```

I am using airtel broadband connection.

Comment: Could you provide additional information? When do these happen? What have you tried? Have you contacted the provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN is a DNS related error, perhaps related to your
Internet supplier (ISP).

Some more information would be useful about your operating system,
geographical location, ISP and router model.
Without that information, I would guess that you are on Windows.

To change your DNS servers from your ISP to Google, do this :

1. Type simultaneously <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, enter `ncpa.cpl` and
   click OK to configure the network connections.
2. Right-click your network adapter and choose **Properties**.
3. Turn off IPv6 by unchecking `Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)`.
4. Click "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and then **Properties**.
5. Enter the following addresses :
   `Preferred DNS server: 8.8.8.8`
   `Alternate DNS server 8.8.4.4`
6. Click OK until all dialogs are closed.
7. In a Command Prompt run as administrator, enter these commands :

   ```
   ipconfig /release
   ipconfig /flushdns  
   ipconfig /renew
   netsh int ip set dns
   netsh winsock reset
   ```
8. Reboot.
9. If the problem continues, reset Chrome : Type `chrome://flags/` in address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
10. Click `Reset all to default` button (right side) and re-launch Chrome.
11. If the problem continues, power the router off and on again.

If the problem still continues, try to see if it arrives with another browser
than Chrome.

Comment: My OS is win 10 & router is asus n10e , india. The problem was with all browsers. I changed the router and problem solved. I used the router at other place and internet connection went down after a day ! I wonder if the router is broken ?

Comment: Impossible to say from over here - I don't know enough about your environment. If it keeps on having problems, then you might assume it's broken or at least unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use [Chrome connectivity diagnostics](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-connectivity-diagn/eemlkeanncmjljgehlbplemhmdmalhdc?hl=en) app to check most steps above. This tool should give you a quick root cause on the issue and maybe help you find answer faster.